# intel xdk- connecting html to php to save values to database using mysqli

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, mysqli

I have 2 files one called 'index.html' and the other called 'student.php'. The index.html code is displayed below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>insert data in database using mysqli</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="main">
<h1>Insert data into database using mysqli</h1>
<div id="login">
<h2>Student's Form</h2>
<hr/>



    <Form Name ="form1" Method ="POST" ACTION = "student.php">


<!--<form action="" method="post"> -->
<label>Student Name :</label>
<input type="text" name="stu_name" id="name" required="required" placeholder="Please Enter Name"/><br /><br />
<label>Student Email :</label>
<input type="email" name="stu_email" id="email" required="required" placeholder="john123@gmail.com"/><br/><br />
<label>Student City :</label>
<input type="text" name="stu_city" id="city" required="required" placeholder="Please Enter Your City"/><br/><br />
<input type="submit" value=" Submit " name="submit"/><br />
</form>
</div>
<!-- Right side div -->

</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

student.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "college";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO students (student_name, student_email, student_city)
VALUES ('".$_POST["stu_name"]."','".$_POST["stu_email"]."','".$_POST["stu_city"]."')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('New record created successfully');</script>";
} else {
echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error."');</script>";
}

$conn->close();
}
?>
```

Once i enter the student name, email and address i click on the submit button. the following error appears on the next page: Cannot POST /http-services/emulator-webserver/ripple/userapp/x/C/xampp/htdocs/xampp/please/www/student.php. I have tested the database connection before and the application is able to connect to the database so this isn't an issue. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: is it possible you need to configure xampp to allow the file to use the `POST` method?

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect the html code to a PHP script by AJAX. whit JSON to transfer the data.

in this video is how to make it work.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NxCeoiouaLs

Comment: i'm using mysqli not mysql, have watched that video and it hasn't helped any :(